# How to save ArayList in Java on MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I have the method set and get:
public class ProdutosPedidoCompraBeans {

```
/**
 * @return the odemNumero
 */
public String getOdemNumero() {
    return odemNumero;
}

/**
 * @param odemNumero the odemNumero to set
 */
public void setOdemNumero(String odemNumero) {
    this.odemNumero = odemNumero;
}

/**
 * @return the codEstoque
 */
public String getCodEstoque() {
    return codEstoque;
}

/**
 * @param codEstoque the codEstoque to set
 */
public void setCodEstoque(String codEstoque) {
    this.codEstoque = codEstoque;
}

/**
 * @return the quantidade
 */
public int getQuantidade() {
    return quantidade;
}

/**
 * @param quantidade the quantidade to set
 */
public void setQuantidade(int quantidade) {
    this.quantidade = quantidade;
}

/**
 * @return the unidade
 */
public String getUnidade() {
    return unidade;
}

/**
 * @param unidade the unidade to set
 */
public void setUnidade(String unidade) {
    this.unidade = unidade;
}

/**
 * @return the descricaoItem
 */
public String getDescricaoItem() {
    return descricaoItem;
}

/**
 * @param descricaoItem the descricaoItem to set
 */
public void setDescricaoItem(String descricaoItem) {
    this.descricaoItem = descricaoItem;
}

/**
 * @return the prazoEntrega
 */
public String getPrazoEntrega() {
    return prazoEntrega;
}

/**
 * @param prazoEntrega the prazoEntrega to set
 */
public void setPrazoEntrega(String prazoEntrega) {
    this.prazoEntrega = prazoEntrega;
}

/**
 * @return the precoUnitario
 */
public float getPrecoUnitario() {
    return precoUnitario;
}

/**
 * @param precoUnitario the precoUnitario to set
 */
public void setPrecoUnitario(float precoUnitario) {
    this.precoUnitario = precoUnitario;
}

/**
 * @return the valorDesconto
 */
public float getValorDesconto() {
    return valorDesconto;
}

/**
 * @param valorDesconto the valorDesconto to set
 */
public void setValorDesconto(float valorDesconto) {
    this.valorDesconto = valorDesconto;
}

/**
 * @return the icmsProduto
 */
public float getIcmsProduto() {
    return icmsProduto;
}

/**
 * @param icmsProduto the icmsProduto to set
 */
public void setIcmsProduto(float icmsProduto) {
    this.icmsProduto = icmsProduto;
}

/**
 * @return the ipiissProduto
 */
public float getIpiissProduto() {
    return ipiissProduto;
}

/**
 * @param ipiissProduto the ipiissProduto to set
 */
public void setIpiissProduto(float ipiissProduto) {
    this.ipiissProduto = ipiissProduto;
}

/**
 * @return the totalProdutoSemImpostos
 */
public float getTotalProdutoSemImpostos() {
    return totalProdutoSemImpostos;
}

/**
 * @param totalProdutoSemImpostos the totalProdutoSemImpostos to set
 */
public void setTotalProdutoSemImpostos(float totalProdutoSemImpostos) {
    this.totalProdutoSemImpostos = totalProdutoSemImpostos;
}

/**
 * @return the totalProdutoComImpostos
 */
public float getTotalProdutoComImpostos() {
    return totalProdutoComImpostos;
}

/**
 * @param totalProdutoComImpostos the totalProdutoComImpostos to set
 */
public void setTotalProdutoComImpostos(float totalProdutoComImpostos) {
    this.totalProdutoComImpostos = totalProdutoComImpostos;
}

/**
 * @return the valorIcmdoProduto
 */
public float getValorIcmdoProduto() {
    return valorIcmdoProduto;
}

/**
 * @param valorIcmdoProduto the valorIcmdoProduto to set
 */
public void setValorIcmdoProduto(float valorIcmdoProduto) {
    this.valorIcmdoProduto = valorIcmdoProduto;
}

/**
 * @return the valorIpiIssdoProduto
 */
public float getValorIpiIssdoProduto() {
    return valorIpiIssdoProduto;
}

/**
 * @param valorIpiIssdoProduto the valorIpiIssdoProduto to set
 */
public void setValorIpiIssdoProduto(float valorIpiIssdoProduto) {
    this.valorIpiIssdoProduto = valorIpiIssdoProduto;
}

/**
 * @return the pesquisaItens
 */
public String getPesquisaItens() {
    return pesquisaItens;
}

/**
 * @param pesquisaItens the pesquisaItens to set
 */
public void setPesquisaItens(String pesquisaItens) {
    this.pesquisaItens = pesquisaItens;
}
```

}

my method DAO is:

public void salvarListaProdutos(ArrayList listaModelProdutos) {

```
    this.conectaPedido.conecta();
    try {
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conectaPedido.conexao.prepareStatement("Insert into compras_itenspedidocompras(odemNumero,codEstoque,quantidade,unidade,descricaoItem,prazoEntrega,precoUnitario,valorDesconto,icmsProduto,ipiissProduto,totalProdutoSemImpostos,totalProdutoComImposto,valorIcmdoProduto,valorIpiIssdoProduto) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

        for (int i = 0; i < listaModelProdutos.size(); i++) {

        pstmt.setString(1, modelProdutos.getOdemNumero());
        pstmt.setString(2, modelProdutos.getCodEstoque());
        pstmt.setInt(3, modelProdutos.getQuantidade());
        pstmt.setString(4, modelProdutos.getUnidade());
        pstmt.setString(5, modelProdutos.getDescricaoItem());
        pstmt.setString(6, modelProdutos.getPrazoEntrega());
        pstmt.setFloat(7, modelProdutos.getPrecoUnitario());
        pstmt.setFloat(8, modelProdutos.getValorDesconto());
        pstmt.setFloat(9, modelProdutos.getIcmsProduto());
        pstmt.setFloat(10, modelProdutos.getIpiissProduto());
        pstmt.setFloat(11, modelProdutos.getTotalProdutoSemImpostos());
        pstmt.setFloat(12, modelProdutos.getTotalProdutoComImpostos());
        pstmt.setFloat(13, modelProdutos.getValorIcmdoProduto());
        pstmt.setFloat(14, modelProdutos.getValorIpiIssdoProduto());
      }
        pstmt.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Itens adicionados ao pedido com sucesso.","",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"erro:"+e,"",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } finally {
        this.conectaPedido.desconecta();
    }
}
```

action of button to save the list on MYSQL:

ArrayList itemTab = new ArrayList<>();
       for(int e = 0; e

```
   modProdutos.setOdemNumero(tabelProduto.getValueAt(e, 0).toString());
   modProdutos.setCodEstoque(tabelProduto.getValueAt(e, 1).toString());
   modProdutos.setQuantidade(Integer.parseInt(tabelProduto.getValueAt(e, 2).toString()));
   modProdutos.setUnidade(tabelProduto.getValueAt(e, 3).toString());
   modProdutos.setDescricaoItem(tabelProduto.getValueAt(e, 4).toString());
   modProdutos.setPrazoEntrega(tabelProduto.getValueAt(e, 5).toString());
   modProdutos.setPrecoUnitario(Float.parseFloat(tabelProduto.getValueAt(e, 6).toString()));
   modProdutos.setValorDesconto(Float.parseFloat(tabelProduto.getValueAt(e, 7).toString()));
   modProdutos.setIcmsProduto(Float.parseFloat(tabelProduto.getValueAt(e, 8).toString()));
   modProdutos.setIpiissProduto(Float.parseFloat(tabelProduto.getValueAt(e, 9).toString()));
   modProdutos.setTotalProdutoSemImpostos(Float.parseFloat(tabelProduto.getValueAt(e, 10).toString()));
   modProdutos.setTotalProdutoComImpostos(Float.parseFloat(tabelProduto.getValueAt(e, 11).toString()));
   modProdutos.setValorIcmdoProduto(Float.parseFloat(tabelProduto.getValueAt(e, 12).toString()));
   modProdutos.setValorIpiIssdoProduto(Float.parseFloat(tabelProduto.getValueAt(e, 13).toString()));

   itemTab.add(modProdutos);

  }
   control.salvarListaProdutos(itemTab);
```

but in the MYSQL Table, the values are as "0" the float fields and as empity Strings fields.

Where have I mistaken?

Comment: I think you have to do a commit after the loop if you have autocommit = false